# zsh pattern matching: only match file names composed of specified characters

Tags: zsh, wildcards

I can print files starting with alpha characters:

```
$ print -l [[:alpha:]]*
```

but how do I print file names that are only composed of alpha characters ?

ie, `aaa` should be printed, but `aaa.txt` should not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn’t a regular expression, it’s a glob, so you need to use zsh [glob operators](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Operators). To repeat a pattern zero or more times, use `#` (which requires `EXTENDED_GLOB` to be set):

```
print -l [[:alpha:]]#
```

Comment: perfect, that works. Should I use parenthesis around the pattern?  `print -l ([[:alpha:]])#`

Comment: In this instance, since there’s only one expression (`[[:alpha:]]`), there’s no need for parentheses. See the `12#` example in the docs.